# Is there any technical benefit in adding semicolons in Swift?

Tags: swift, syntax

I wrote couple of programs in Objective-C.
I've seen that Swift syntax does not require use of semicolons.

My question is - is there any technical point in using them anyway?

Comment: You do need to put them for consecutive declarations - I also sometimes use them to assign variables on the same line to save space.

Comment: @noɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC That's probably the only reason to use semicolon in Swift, however it's also one of the code practices that is generally frowned upon and forbidden in evert style guideline.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is: No.

Swift does not require a semicolon after each statement in your code. They are only required if you wish to combine multiple statements on a single line.

Do not write multiple statements on a single line separated with semicolons.

**Preferred:**

```
var swift = "not a scripting language"
```

**Not Preferred:**

```
var swift = "not a scripting language";
```

For more informations, please refer to this page:
https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#semicolons

Comment: Swift does not care. There are no preferred ways.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, you can write multiple statements in one line. For example you could write statements more compact when needed, for example:

```
var progress: Progress {
    get { _progress.value }
    set { _progress.value = newValue; parent?.update() }
}
```

Use sparingly though. But in this specific case I prefer it instead of expanding everything to a separate line since its still quite readable and only 2 statements.

Comment: I would rather say "do not use". There is no situation when this is beneficial. Significantly decreases code readibility.

Comment: Well it saves 5 lines, so one could argue there are exceptions to the rule. There is a fine line between readability and verbosity.

Comment: It is not less verbose, its just compressed. Such things are forbidden in any coding guidelines - and for obvious reasons. One command per line has been the norm for decades. It's not uncommon to intentionally split complex commands to multiple lines only to increase readability. You should probably use your IDE's code collapsing instead..

Answer (score 1):

There are (or used to be) situations where two separate statements on two different lines would taken by the compiler as a single statement. The typical locus is `return` followed by another statement that you don't want executed. In that situation, and in that situation alone, the semicolon is crucial.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    return // need semicolon here
    print(1) // oops
}
```

However, in modern Swift the compiler warns and compensates. Adding a semicolon (`return;`) quiets the warning (though it then causes a different warning).

Otherwise, a semicolon never has any technical benefit.

Comment: Sure it has. You can e.g. write 2 statements in one line.